# Regex replace a set of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace `+` `-` `(` `)` and `space` with an empty character in a Javascript string. The expression I'm using is:

```
"+1 - (042) - 123456".replace(/[\+\-\' '\(\)]/, "");
```

which results in:

```
"1 - (042) - 123456"
```

Only the `+` is replaced and not the other characters. What is the error in my expression?

Comment: Most characters in a class don't need escaping: `[-+'() ]`

Comment: Note that if you want to strip out all non-digits could use `\D` the negation of `\d` which is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[0-9]`: Replace `/\D+/g` with empty string (besides the reason why it failed which is answered already).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use square brackets to list characters to remove/change or whatever, you don't want to escape them. And I would recommend using `\s` instead of , and, of course, you need the global flag - `g`.

```
"+1 - (042) - 123456".replace(/[+()\s-]/g, "")
```

Comment: Your answers definitely provides a solution, but you should explain why and how you changed the OP’s code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the g flag:

```
/[\+\-\' '\(\)]/g
```

JS:

```
"+1 - (042) - 123456".replace(/[\+\-\' '\(\)]/g, "");
```

The `g` indicates a "Global search", meaning that every match of the regex must be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `g` global flag inorder to make pattern to match two or more times on the same line. And alo you don't need to include single quotes inside the character class.

```
"+1 - (042) - 123456".replace(/[-+() ]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

As idmean mentioned in their answer , you should add the g(global) flag , otherwise the function will stop once the first match is found .

However , there are some redundant escapes and characters in your RegEx.

That's how your RegEx can be in its simplest form :

```
/[+) (-]/g
```

I didn't get why there are single quotes in your RegEx.